# Using the reshape function in R with multiple matching rows

Tags: r, reshape

So I have the following data frame `df`:

```
       X     Y     Z     ID     value
1      0    20    135    a       20
2      0    20    135    a       30
3      0    20    135    b       40
4      20   104    20    c       10
5      20   104    20    b       15
...
```

I want a final output of

```
       X     Y     Z     a     b     c     
1      0    20    135    20    40    null
2      0    20    135    30    null  null
3      20   104    20    null  15    10
...
```

I'd like to turn all the different IDs to individual columns holding the values from the original data frame. What I'm currently doing is 
`reshape(df, idvar=c("X", "Y", "Z"), timevar="ID", direction="wide")`. However, this results in warnings of having multiple rows match for each of `a` `b` and `c`, and thus only the first are taken. I want a row for each unique `X`, `Y`, `Z` combination but since there are many repeated measurements I want multiple rows for each combination as well, but the number of repeated measurements differs for each `a`, `b`, and `c`. Is there any way of doing this effectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already identify the answer in your question: You need to add a secondary "id" variable. This is easily done with `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package. Here's what it does:

```
library(splitstackshape)
getanID(mydf, c("X", "Y", "Z", "ID"))
#     X   Y   Z ID value .id
# 1:  0  20 135  a    20   1
# 2:  0  20 135  a    30   2
# 3:  0  20 135  b    40   1
# 4: 20 104  20  c    10   1
# 5: 20 104  20  b    15   1
```

With that in mind, here's how you would change your current `reshape` approach:

```
reshape(getanID(mydf, c("X", "Y", "Z", "ID")), 
        direction = "wide", idvar = c("X", "Y", "Z", ".id"), timevar = "ID")
#     X   Y   Z .id value.a value.b value.c
# 1:  0  20 135   1      20      40      NA
# 2:  0  20 135   2      30      NA      NA
# 3: 20 104  20   1      NA      15      10
```

Or, since "data.table" is also loaded with "splitstackshape", you can use `dcast.data.table`, like this:

```
dcast.data.table(getanID(mydf, c("X", "Y", "Z", "ID")),
                 X + Y + Z + .id ~ ID, value.var = "value")
#     X   Y   Z .id  a  b  c
# 1:  0  20 135   1 20 40 NA
# 2:  0  20 135   2 30 NA NA
# 3: 20 104  20   1 NA 15 10
```

Comment: what if I want value 40 of column b to be distributed to all ids?? (1: and 2: also)